# spring hibernate handle value not found

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

What is the best way to handle NullPointerException in spring and hibernate? My methods in dao layer current surround with try catch block and it looks quiet messy and abundant. I read some article and people suggest that I should let spring handle the exception. Is that a true statement? Because I have no idea how I can let spring handle it (surround try catch block in the service layer instead of dao lol)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, these kind of questions always have of opinion based answers.Though there are these practices called best practices. You might see lots of different type of opinions.

And since you are talking about null pointer exception you are going to see more different opinions :)

On the other hand, what do I think ? Most of the people would probably agree that you need to just throw exceptions on dao layer to be handles at some other point.

Obviously you are talking about a web application here. Lets assume it is not a null pointer exception but another kind of exception (because i think null pointer exception should be thought differently)

1- Exceptions other than NullPointerException:

Business logic is processed on service layer, so if there is an exception say on database like a constraint exception, it is generally the layer you should be handling these exceptions and provide appropriate verbose messages to the interested parties (error messages on screen for users, appropriate informative messages in log files etc.). Because business logic and how exceptions should be handled logically should be here.

I can go on more and more thinking of other perspectives, it is a broad subject related to other topics. Involving transactions, role of service layer, etc.

2- Null pointer exceptions:
Null pointer exceptions I think should never occur in a well tested application. That is because, if you are going to execute some logic on some data (parameters passed, variables etc.), you should already have all necessary information initialized to execute that logic.

If not, you should just check if a value is initialized or not and throw an exception denoting data is not initialized (NullPointerException is about that too actually.) But should you always perform null checks ? That is another subject, it is about who invokes your code, if it is a code  block coded in a way that actually can not be invoked with null values (private methods, some back-end code only used by certain codes etc.)

So you see it is a long story. But a good practice would be just to throw checked exceptions and let runtime exceptions handled where it should be handled. (Not always of course)